# WordPress не видит стандартные функции

Tags: wordpress

Создал в корне темы папку с php файлами. Когда пытаюсь в этих файлах запустить стандартные функции (например: `update_post_meta`), возвращает 500 ошибку, а в логах пишет `Call to undefined function update_post_meta() in ...`.  Может, свои php файлы где-то нужно подключать, чтобы в них можно было вызвать стандартные функции WP?

Comment: А для чего, собственно, вы используете эти php файлы?

Comment: Я ответил, но лучше все делать правильно, внутри WordPress, например в functions.php своей темы

Comment: @Pyramidhead, в этих файлах обрабатываются только ajax запросы

Comment: ajax тоже так не делают, почитайте, как надо в WP: https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html

Comment: @r.mcreal, KAGG Design правильно заметил, что для работы с ajax в WordPress есть свой довольно простой и удобный механизм.

Comment: @KAGG Design, вы конечно все правильно говорите, но в моем случае нужно закончить как можно быстрее. Данные у меня приходят все нормально, а вот передать эти данные в стандартную функцию WP я не могу

Comment: Идти неправильным путём  может оказаться намного дольше :) И опаснее.

Comment: @SeVlad как тут три раза плюсануть )))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо инициализировать WordPress.

```
/** Load WordPress Bootstrap */
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' );
```

Comment: Пробовал прописать это в файле, но не сработало. Все равно не видит функцию

Comment: Может мне путь на другой поменять?

Comment: Разберитесь с путем к файлу wp-load.php. Он в корне WP.

Comment: @ KAGG Design, попробовал так  `require_once ('/wp-load.php');`  в логах пишет `require_once(/wp-load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/mySite/data/www/mySite.ru/wp-content/themes/classipress/myFiles/handler.php on line 3, referer: http://mySite.ru/create-listing/?step=gateway-select&hash=f612a0955e1c13a1280f`

Comment: `require_once ('/wp-load.php');` в этом случае, он же должен из корня брать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, помогите! А то придется быдлокодить(

Comment: Напишите именно так, как я сказал. Это дает путь в корень сайта, например /var/www/test-site/wp-load.php

Comment: а то, что вы пишите - неправильно /wp-load.php - эта конструкция ищет wp-load.php в корне диска

Comment: Блин, вы же в корне темы создаете! Я не заметил. Тогда так: `/var/www/mySite/data/www/mySite.ru/wp-load.php`

Comment: Исправил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Сработало)

Comment: мамадорогая... KAGG Design ты ли это? Какие нафик серверные пути в файлах..

Comment: @SeVlad у ТС не запущен WordPress, значит, нет ABSPATH со всеми вытекающими

Comment: И что с того? когда отменили серверные ($_SERVER) переменные php?

Comment: @SeVlad я ему как проще хотел. Но ок, устыдил, перепишу ответ )

Comment: Ну вот, другое дело. А то я уже за тебе переживать начал :) Надо ж не забывать что ответы читают и др. люди :)